# How to use 'WP_Query' or 'query_posts' to display content in a descending order

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

How can I list posts in a descending order of the `$json_data->data[0]->total_count` values ? I want to display top shared posts descending, but I can't really use `WP_Query` or `query_posts` the right way.

```
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
query_posts('&showposts=-1');

while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( array(40,40) );
    }

    $url = get_the_permalink();
    $json = file_get_contents( 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20like_count,%20total_count,%20share_count,%20click_count,%20comment_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20=%20%27' . $url . '%27' );
    $json_data = json_decode($json, false);
    echo $json_data->data[0]->total_count;

    endwhile;
```

The above code shows posts and total share count but not in a descending order because yet I haven't applied any rule.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the counts as key and link a value and sort them before display like this :

```
$sort_tab = array();
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail( array(40,40) );
}

$url = get_the_permalink();
$json = file_get_contents( 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20like_count,%20total_count,%20share_count,%20click_count,%20comment_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20=%20%27' . $url . '%27' );
$json_data = json_decode($json, false);
$sort_tab[$json_data->data[0]->total_count] = $url;

endwhile;
sort($sort_tab);

foreach($sort_tab as $count=>$link)
{
    echo $link.' has '.$count.' votes';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Antoine !! works like a charm!
Still, it doesn't show the entire posts only 18 out of total..

Comment: You are welcome. Instead of query_posts, I personnaly prefer to use WP_Query class. In your case that should be :
$query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>-1));
Also, in your while, replace have_posts and the_post by $query->have_posts and $query->the_post. Don't forget to add wp_reset_query() after endwhile;

Tell me if it works better =)

Comment: Thanks a lot again, but unfortunately it still shows data for 18 posts only, I don't know what I am missing.
Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/gUKti9hR

Comment: This may sound silly but ... are you sure you have more than 18 records in the database ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure! I can list them all using `query_posts('&showposts=-1');` but with your code I can't..

Comment: According to the documentation, $query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=-1' ); should show all your posts. Maybe you can try to log $query->$post_count to see how many posts the query does retrieve

Comment: Thanks! I am now using JavaScript to sort data descending since I couldn't do it with PHP.
Thank you for the continuous help !!